# Change scope from inside of ng-repeat from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have html like this:

```
<div dir-paginate="x in comments | itemsPerPage: commentsPerPage">
HERE IS DIRECTIVE FROM BLEOW
</div>
```

I need to change `commentsPerPage` scope from dictive...

Here is directive, this directive is inside ng-repeat:

```
angular.module('commentsApp')
        .directive("addreply", addreply);



//ADD REPLY FUNCTION
function addreply(createCommentFactory)
{
    //CREATING BUTTON FOR REPLY AND CALL LINK FUNCTION
    var addReplys = {
        link: link,
        restrict: "EA",
        transclude: true
    };

    return addReplys;

    function link(scope, element, attrs)
    {
        scope.form = {
            reply: ""
        };



        //CALL FACTORY TO ADD NEW REPLAY ON CLICK
        element.bind('click', function () {
            scope.addReply = function (el) {
                createCommentFactory.saveComment(scope.form.reply[el.id], scope.project_id, el.id, el.level + 1)
                        .success(function (data) {
                            scope.commentsPerPage = scope.comments.length;
                        })
                        .error(function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                // RESET REPLY TEXT AREA
                scope.form.reply = "";
            };

        });
    }
}
```

you see my try inside `scope.commentsPerPage = scope.comments.length;` but not working... Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your directive's scope is prototypically inheriting from the parent's scope.  So `scope.commentsPerPage` is actually a shadowed version of the parent's `scope.commentsPerPage`.

As a quick fix, you can use `$parent.commentsPerPage`.  As a more long-term solution, you should restructure your code to use `controller.property` rather than `scope.property` syntax.

You can check out [this article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) for an in-depth explanation.

Comment: But you was right  I can access to parent like this: `scope.$parent.commentsPerPage` ... Could you explain me what you think about `controller.property` ? Do you this to use something like this `var vm = this;
    vm.formEdit = formEdit;` ??